# HyperLedger Fabric Composer TypeError: Channel options must be an object with string keys and integer or string values

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

While executing the below command:-

```
composer network deploy -a my-network.bna -p hlfv1 -i admin -s adminpw
```

I am getting the error below:

> TypeError: Channel options must be an object with string keys and integer or string values
>       Command failed

## System Details

Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be
Node version 6.9.1
Npm version 3.10.8
Python 2.7.12
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Memory 3.71Gb
Fabric-Composer v0.9

```
docker ps -a :- IMAGE NAMES
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-org-acme-biznet-0.9.1
hyperledger/composer-playground
hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.0.0-rc1 
hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-1.0.0-rc1 
hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.0.0-rc1
hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.0.0-rc1

./startFabric.sh :- creates and joins the following channel
```

## Create the channel

```
docker exec peer0.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c composerchannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/composer-channel.tx
```

## Join peer0.org1.example.com to the channel.

```
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel join -b composerchannel.block
```

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed you're using the fabric-tools dev setup from https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html

the `docker exec` in startFabric.sh (refers to fabric-scripts/hlfv1/startFabric.sh) is as you've shown above.

I suggest to get the latest composer release (today's is v0.9.2) and Fabric (v1.0 GA edition now available with those scripts). Follow the sequence below.

1) pull down the new fabric-dev-scripts (see here for info https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html )

2) perform a teardown.sh

3) remove your old docker *images*

4) downloadFabric.sh (from within fabric-tools of your new scripts)

5) startFabric.sh

6) createComposerProfile.sh (for the new env) to get new admin credentials - then re-create your archive bna using this latest composer version - but use PeerAdmin when deploying the network, not 'admin' as shown below:

`composer network deploy -a my-network.bna -p hlfv1 -i PeerAdmin -s adminpw`

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same problem. I have an existing fabric network setup in my local machine. After that I started a fabric composer container using docker script, and when trying to deploy a network or trying to open the editor in browser, it gives the same error - "TypeError: Channel options must be an object with string keys and integer or string values()"
So basically, I don't want to use composer script to setup a new fabric network for me. I want to deploy to an existing network and that's when it fails with the above error.